# Why I am returning integers instead of characters in the 3rd and 4th print statement?

Tags: java, unicode

Can you please explain what's going in the last 2 print statements?  That's where I    get lost.

```
public class Something
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char whatever = '\u0041';

        System.out.println( '\u0041'); //prints A as expected

        System.out.println(++whatever); //prints B as expected

        System.out.println('\u0041' + 1); //prints 66 I understand the unicode of 1     adds up the 
        //unicode representing 66 but why am I even returning an integer when in the previous statement I returned a char?

        System.out.println('\u0041' + 'A'); //prints 130 I just wanted to show that adding an 
        //integer to the unicode in the previous print statement is not implicit casting because 
        //here I add a char which does not implicitly cast char on the returned value

    }
}
```

Comment: Since `char`s are casted as `int`. If you want to concatenate the values, turn them into `String`s.

Comment: The conversion from char to int is implicit in Java.

Comment: Charecters are nothing but integers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because of [**Binary Numeric Promotion**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#170983)

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order, using widening conversion (§5.1.2) to convert operands as necessary:
>
> - If any of the operands is of a reference type, unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) is performed. Then:
> - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
> - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
> - Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int.

Basically, both operands are converted to an `int`, and then the `System.out.println(int foo)` is called. The only types that can be returned by `+`, `*`, etc. are `double`, `float`, `long`, and `int`

Comment: Okay well what about the last print statement?
Is the unicode and 'A' not considered the same type?

Comment: @KacyRaye. See that last condition in that link. The promotion at the least is to `int`. So, result of any binary expression can be minimum an `int` type.

Comment: Me and two tutors at my school had to work together to understand that answer, but we finally understood everything you were saying lol.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`'\u0041' + 1` produces `int`, you need to cast it to `char` so that javac binds the call to `println(char`) instead of `prinln(int)`

```
System.out.println((char)('\u0041' + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

`whatever` is a char, and `++whatever` means `whatever = whatever + 1` (ignoring prefix order)

since there is an assignment involved, result is converted to char, so the char method is called. But in 3-4th print, there is no assignment, and as per rule, all the sum operation are by default happens in int. So before print operation, it sums up the `char + char` and `char+int`,  and since there is no back assignment, it remains as int after the opration, so the integer method is called.